# 12 hour shifts or 8 hours

Tags: job-change

I was hired 10 years ago, agreeing to work 8 hr shifts. Recently, most people have voluntarily switched to 12 hour shifts. It has caused a lot of inadequate staffing issues, with people working 2 different shifts.  They haven't asked me to switch to 12 hour shift, but can they force me to if they want to?

Comment: What does your employment contract say?

Comment: You haven't said where you are, so we have no idea what laws might apply. In an employment at will situation such as most US jobs, the simple answer is that they can redefine the job to make a specific schedule a requirement,  leaving you with the choice of accepting the change or seeking employment elsewhere.  Of course that negotiation goes both ways if you're someone they'd rather not lose.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are in the U.S., Fair Labor Standards Act (federal labor laws) states that an employer can require you to work 12 hour days.  In fact it says that they don't even have to give you a break during the 12 hours.

Most states have break requirements but most do not make any significant changes between 8 and 12 hour workdays.  However some do and you will have to look up the specific labor laws for your state.  I know that some states have hourly limits based on the type of occupation you have - factory work, trucker, logger, heavy machinery.  Most of these laws focus on safety but for sure some are due to union efforts.

The fact that your employer has gone to 12 hour shifts tell me they are in a state that doesn't have any specifications on this (or they are ignorant of the laws).  Another thing that employers have to deal with is some states require overtime pay based on an 8 hour day and not a 40 hour week.

What can you do?  It depends on your state but probably not much at all.

My advice?  Give it a try.  I moved my helpdesk engineers to either 3x12 (4 days every 3 weeks) or 4x10 shifts.  Literally no one would leave our group after.  It almost got to the point where people were waiting for a lateral opening in my group.  They just loved the extra days off and less commuting time.  I know it isn't for everyone but it does allow you to live a more flexible life.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they do have to give you a break: 10 minutes paid break every four hours and a half hour meal break for shifts over 5 hours.

Comment: @kevincline - Like I said FLSA does not have any provisions for breaks.  However almost all states have regulations that are in line with your comment.

Comment: @kevincline - most states also require that their (states') regulations must be posted in a prominent place frequented by employees (such as a breakroom, or near the timeclock).  You can also (usually) download PDF's of the required posters from your state's Dept of Labor and Employment.  Just found a nice list of Colorado's:  http://www.ucdenver.edu/about/departments/HR/HRPolicesGuidlines/Documents/EmploymentLawPoster.pdf

Comment: @WesleyLong - good point.  These have always been in cafeteria or break room at my work places.

Comment: appreciate all the responses guys.....answers were very helpful :)